# Modify behavior of WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, file, filter

I have an own server with WordPress installed on it.
I understood that WordPress wants to protect the users by forbidding scripts in a post written by users.

I don't like it, so I looked for a solution.
The first entry/place of [this](http://www.presscoders.com/2012/12/10-things-i-hate-about-wordpress/) post says, that I have to use:

```
remove_filter("the_content", "wpautop");
```

But I can't find the name of the file I have to modify. My question is: *which file of WordPress do I have to modify?*

Comment: Did you try a search on the files in your WordPress folder for "remove_filter" or whatever?  That is how I always hack apart WordPress.

Comment: It clearly says where to put that line of code `functions.php`. Check your themes folder

Comment: @tlenns I don't know how I could oversee this. That's way too stupid for me :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you enable and disable things in the functions.php file. Try adding that line to the beginning of your file.

The file is in your template's folder at /wp-content/themes/your-template-name.